# I want a Unit Test Failure not to break build

Tags: ant, testng

I'm using ant to do my builds, and I'm using TestNG for testing.
Is it possible to not have the build fail whenever there is a test failure?

And, should I have a test method throw an Exception, or catch any exceptions that my be thrown in the method?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the build to fail if there is a test failure?

Comment: build is more compilation related, a test failure is more functional related

Comment: because a build breaking affects everyone including the developer who needs to find why the test fails. And the test may be insignificant. The build should go on. You might keep the old versions for usage in case there's an error but there is no way a broken test should ever be considered fatal to the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task you can set `haltonfailure` property.

The quote from ant documentation:

> haltonfailure - Stop the build process if a test fails (errors are
>   considered failures as well).

The sample:

```
<target name="test_skip_test">
    <echo>before test call</echo>
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>

        <test name="UnitTest1" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
        </test>
    </junit>        
    <echo>after test call</echo>
</target>
```

Or you can use `failureproperty` property.

The quote from ant documentation:

> failureproperty - The name of a property to set in the event of a
>   failure (errors are considered failures as well). Overrides value set
>   in <junit>.